# Tridion CM 2013 SP Install - Blank Page?

Tags: 2013, 2013-sp1, installation

I'm trying to install a dev instance of tridion 2013 SP1 CM.  The DB has been set up.  The install ran without errors, but when I went to the CM home page I just get a blank page?   I looked in eventvwr.  I did see a DB error related to TCMDBUser account, so I assigned it sysadmin rights.  Now I don't see the DB error, but I still get a blank page instead of the CM home.

Where do I look for problems? How do I figure out what is wrong.  There are no errors in the tridion log & now no errors come in the event log either.

Comment: I hope you are using the Internet Explorer and due to some default security settings in IE you may get this issue. Have you tried it with FireFox or Chrome Browser?
On the other hand you may try by Ensuring the IE settings as per the recommendation

Comment: I am using Chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, you can disable sysadmin rights because that's not required and not recommended.

have you tried adding the site to the local intranet? what browser and version are you using?

**EDIT**

Cause was [URLScan](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/urlscan), as mentioned in comments below.

Comment: I'm using Chrome.  I noticed that I get a 404 for SDL.UI.Core.Knockout.js?1.0.0.1253.  Working instances of the CM are not getting a 404 for that .

Comment: That file appears to be in the correct location on the server.

Comment: FYI, I discovered what was blocking that file.  We use a utility called URLScan.  The utility did not like the dots in the query string.